# How to do page redirect with Angular UI Router so back button doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

When a user submits a form on my site, I want to redirect them to the next state in my application using `Angular UI Router` so the user can't hit their back button to go back or refresh button to resubmit the form. But I don't want to do a page refresh.

I've tried these but didn't work:

```
$location.path('/myPath').replace();
$state.transitionTo('about', {}, { location: 'replace' });
```

How can I redirect users to another state in `AngularJS` with the `Angular UI Router`?

Comment: reset the form `model` after submission, it will prevent duplicate entry

Comment: Angular is a SPA framework, and as such, it's not really compatible with the the PRG pattern.

Comment: Angular UI Router has the default functionality of updating the browser 
history stack (window.history object). The back and forward buttons rely on the browser's history. So i guess you have to use other simple XMLHttpRequest APIs , if you want users not to access the previous state with back button

Comment: Agree with @Saqueib, keep it simple and just clear the form upon successful form submittal so they can't resubmit the form. Simply show a prompt or message on the page letting them know the form was submitted successfully and leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the new state and use the location:replace option

```
$state.go('about', {}, { location: 'replace' });
```

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#options